# "show/hide" a div with javascript not jquery, and not with display:none

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, visibility, display

I need to show/hide up and down a div, but:

- It can't be with jquery: because, togle(), slideTogle(), fade, animate, etc, they all use display:none, and I need the div using it space in the DOM (I'll be procesing things there).

Til now, I only made that divs get the style visibility: hidden and block, by clickin some "Toggle" button, it works ok, but I don't know how to add some effect on the display, like togle('slow') does.

My CSS:

```
.show, .show * {
    visibility: inherit  !important;
}

.hide, .hide * {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

My React/js:

```
toggleCharts:function(){
    //$("#chartBox").toggle();
    if (this.state.className === 'hide')
        this.setState({className: 'show'});
    else
        this.setState({className: 'hide'});
}
```

The Div to hide:

```
<div id="chartBox" className={this.state.className}></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your React/jQ as-is, but show and hide your elements with CSS transitions, like fading with opacity:

```
.show {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

.hide {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

Comment: I wastrying something like that, let's see.

Comment: Works 99% great, except for one reason, one of the child elements of the div now are colored black, but I'll have to check why. Let me try the other answer as well (but as I said, i don't want to use jquery...)

Comment: @pmirnd Is it possible that child was originally semi-transparent with opacity? You actually don't need the `, .show *` and `, .hide *` rules because hiding/showing the parent element is enough - that may fix it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ahh yes, that element (is a c3.js chart) has opacity 0, so with .show I'm setting it as 1. I'm doing that because some elements were "visibility: visible" and I need to make them ALL as hidden", that's why my original css was: * visibility: hidden or inherit. With inherit all the child elements become or hidden or visible

Comment: @pmirnd Did my adjustment of removing the wildcard selectors fix the issue? That was applicable with `visibility` but won't matter with `opacity`.

Comment: "That was applicable with visibility but won't matter with opacity" <--- ahhh, gotcha. Let me try.

Comment: Nice! now works totally. Thanks man, didn't know that about opacity.

Answer (score 1):

try : `$('#chartBox').animate({opacity : 0}, 500);`

Comment: Well, I said that it can't be jQuery, but thanks (didn't worked)

Comment: yes, but your problem was with `display: none` , in this case, the display property is not touched, only the opacity is changed